# I am getting error in APNS implementation

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I am getting error in APNS implementation
I used code from here
http://www.easyapns.com/apple-delegate

I get following error

Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 UserInfo=0x12f9f0 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application"

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For developing apps with push notification you need to create appCertificate for push notification and sign the app with that.

Comment: i generated certificate where it say for "Apple Push Notification service" that  "Enabled for Development".I think no need of another certificate ?

Comment: No you need to sign the app with that.

Comment: No you don't need other certificate. Just sign the app with that one.

Comment: every thing is ok but problem remained same